# Release of a web application: advice / to do list

Tags: web-applications, web, language-agnostic, saas, release-management

Ok, i need some advice about this topic. Let's say I'm developing a web app that is not finished yet (and never will be :) ). Today, talking with a friend, I was thinking about the first release, and I would like to hear from you what I MUST do before that day.

First of all: should I go live with a solid couple of basic features or wait till there's something more interesting? This is because the core is fully functioning, I even have some advanced features, but approssimately the 40% are nothing more than drafts.

(Closed) Beta: my friend suggested to starting launch a closed beta, and only when in a really stable, fully featured deploy to the public. Is this a good practice? Does it have some real benefit compared to an early public release?

ie I have user management, but I can't export nothing more than plain simple user reports. In this case reports are not a key feature, but still something worth having. Should I go live when this feature is ready? Can I ship it now, and update later with these new features? This question obviously applies for many other points, user reports are only a specific example.

Billing: I plain to ask for some bucks to create pro accounts. Pro users can take advantage of some advanced features (some of them are ready, other will be before the release. Just a couple of them are planned for late development). Should I leave everything free for now, and then introduce billing? Or the best bet is to start with those distinctions?

Bugs: since the application itself is very simple in this moment, there are no serious bugs, but I'm 100% sure that some glitch, minor bug etc could be released. Should I put huge effort on finding those little glitches, or do I let my users / beta testers do the testing for me?

Performance: I never ever ever put any effort in this way. Since I don't plan to release a killer app, I thought this point it's not worth my time, but someone can prove me wrong.

Disaster recovery: sh*t happens. I don't have any disaster recovery procedure, but I think I really need one, even in early stage. Any useful advice on what to do? I was thinking about backups (database, user data).

Development blog: is worth having one?

Promotion: In case of early release, should I promote the app through online advertising, or should I wait for a more featured version?

Am i missing some points? I would really hear from you, and feel free to add any consideration, any problem you have encountered. In general, any advice you can give me.

Lastly, I'm sorry for my awful english, I hope the question is still comprehensible.

**EDIT:**
Browsing Jeff Atwood's Coding horror, i found this:

[Version 1 Sucks, But Ship It Anyway](http://blog.codinghorror.com/version-1-sucks-but-ship-it-anyway/)

I think it's a good reply for my first question. Someone who doesn't agree? And can explain why?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to be received as a company/developer and on what is most advantageous for you in a business sense.

Some questions you might want to consider:

*Is it important to get on the market as soon as possible?
How are new updates/features going to be handled? (Side question, will people have to pay for new versions?)
Will my user's care about all the nuts and bolts that go into developing?*

Hopefully this will lead you into some ways of thinking that will help you find the answers you're looking for.

Just to actually answer some of your questions..

1. I'd go live with a core set of features and then introduce new features as they become available (research iterative deployments)
2. Free basic app first so people can get an idea of what its all about, then make a pro version
3. Google "80/20 rule software bugs" and then make a decision
4. Poorly performing pieces of software tend to turn users away
5. Yes, make backups of everything
6. Have a blog where users can see what is going on with your app
7. The more people who know about your app, the more you can eventually monetize it